# Iterate Values in React Nested Array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

I have a problem iterating values of nested array in my react app.

I want the output to be like this"

```
Shopping
    Food
    Drink
    
Sports
   Basketball
   Soccer
```

Pls check my codesandbox here [CLICK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/field-array-material-ui-dialog-mcrlp?file=/src/Salary.jsx)

```
{results.map((data, index) => (
        <ul>
          <li>
            <div>{data["key"]} </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      ))}
```

Comment: can you explain more clearly. I have seen your code but still It is confusing. ```Results``` is an array of objects. When you are mapping Results array you will get object in ```data``` variable. But in your data object there is no key with the name of ```key```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
import React from "react";

const Salary = () => {
  const results = [
    {
      ID: "shops",
      Shopping: [
        { ID: "food.order", Name: "Food" },
        { ID: "drink.order", Name: "Drink" }
      ]
    },
    {
      ID: "fun",
      Sports: [
        { ID: "play.basketball", Name: "Basketball" },
        { ID: "play.soccer", Name: "Soccer" }
      ]
    }
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {results.map((data, i) =>
          Object.keys(data)
            .filter((x) => Array.isArray(data[x]))
            .map((key) => (
              <div key={data.ID}>
                <li>{key}</li>
                <ul>
                  {data[key].map((item) => (
                    <li key={item.ID}>{item.Name}</li>
                  ))}
                </ul>
              </div>
            ))
        )}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Salary;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix `salary.jsx` like this. To get correct key, you have to use `Object.keys(data)[1]` instead of `data["key"]`.

```
import React from "react";

const Salary = () => {
  const results = [
    {
      ID: "shops",
      Shopping: [
        { ID: "food.order", Name: "Food" },
        { ID: "drink.order", Name: "Drink" }
      ]
    },
    {
      ID: "fun",
      Sports: [
        { ID: "play.basketball", Name: "Basketball" },
        { ID: "play.soccer", Name: "Soccer" }
      ]
    }
  ];
  
  const format = (data) => {
    const key = Object.keys(data)[1];
    const text = data[key].reduce((prev, cur) => {
      return prev + ' ' + cur.Name;
    }, '')
    return key + text;
  }
  return (
    <div>
      {results.map((data) => (
        <ul>
          <li>
            <div> {format(data)} </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Salary;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason you have a problem with iterating over `results` is because it's not in a good shape:
try this if you can:

```
import React from "react";

const Salary = () => {
  const results = [
    {
      ID: "shops",
      Name: "Shopping",
      subs: [
        { ID: "food.order", Name: "Food" },
        { ID: "drink.order", Name: "Drink" }
      ]
    },
    {
      ID: "fun",
      Name: "Sports",
      subs: [
        { ID: "play.basketball", Name: "Basketball" },
        { ID: "play.soccer", Name: "Soccer" }
      ]
    }
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      {results.map((data, index) => (
        <ul key={data.ID}>
          <li>
            <div>{data.Name}</div>
            {data.subs.length &&
              data.subs.map((innerData) => (
                <ul key={innerData.ID}>
                  <li>
                    <div>{innerData.Name}</div>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              ))}
          </li>
        </ul>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Salary;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this snippet. Use nested `map` and provide `key` attribute for all `li`

```js
const Salary = () => {
  const results = [
    {
      ID: "shops",
      Shopping: [
        { ID: "food.order", Name: "Food" },
        { ID: "drink.order", Name: "Drink" }
      ]
    },
    {
      ID: "fun",
      Sports: [
        { ID: "play.basketball", Name: "Basketball" },
        { ID: "play.soccer", Name: "Soccer" }
      ]
    }
  ];

  return (
  <div>
    <ul>
      {results.map((data) => (
        <li key={data.id}>
          {data.ID}
          <ul>
            {(data.Sports || data.Shopping).map((item) => (
              <li key={item.ID}> {item.Name} </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Salary />, document.querySelector('#app'))
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<div id="app"> </div>
```